# How to read scalar, vector and matrix information in string format resembling Python syntax in R?

Tags: python, r, parsing, matrix

I have strings that contain scalars, vectors, and matrices, e.g.

"[0,1],[[1,2],[3,4]],42"

And following the same example, that input in R should give me this:

```
[[1]]
[1] 0 1

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

[[3]]
[1] 42
```

So the notation is similar to that of Python where matrices are actually lists of lists.

Should I just write a parser for this, or has somebody already done that or is there a simple and neat trick to achieve this with no or only a little effort?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```r
x <- "[0,1],[[1,2],[3,4]],42"
xx <- paste0("[", x, "]")
jsonlite::fromJSON(xx)
```

Comment: Wow, of course, this is beautiful. BTW this method supports string elements too. One needs only to escape the corresponding quotation marks like:
"1,2,[1,2],\"cow\",[[1,2],[3,4]], \"cat\""

Comment: The matrices need to be transposed to match the output in the question.